# T SQL Group By Having Count of returning wrong data

Tags: t-sql

I have a complex t-sql query "for me anyway" that isn't functioning the way I need it to.
The query is designed to return simular records unioned across two databases that have simular records in each database.
If a product fails, it will be assigned a "Failed" in one DB, or a "PF" in the other DB. "PR" means "PRODUCT READY" in both.
I am trying to return a list that includes only "Failed or PF" data that has < two records based on the ProdNo column.
"This is to prompt the employee to test the product again", if 2 records exist in either DB, no action is needed."
My query breaks down when I try to limit the results to show only entries that have less than 2 duplicate "ProdNo" values.
In other words, a product is produced and given a ProdNo number. After testing, it can be marked as a PR, PF, or Failed.
My query should never produce any results with PR, yet when a test is performed several days after the original test, PR values appear in my results.

Here is the query with notes.

---

```
-- 1st half of union query

-- Find all run failed's that do not have a PR'ed 2nd test.

Declare @daysback int
set @daysback = -2

select min(sid3)as 'ProdNo',
    min([Timestamp])as 'TimeS',
    min(Burn) as 'type',
    min(Mixer) as 'Mixer'
from [Stat].[dbo].[oedata]  
where sid3 IN 
(
-- Find run faileds and PRs in Stat db 

    SELECT [sid3]
    from [Stat].[dbo].[oedata]
    where (type ='wos') and (burn = 'failed')
    and (Flag = '128')
)
 --- Limit Results to return only instances of 1 record

AND [Timestamp] > DATEADD( d, @daysback, getdate())
group by Sid3 
having COUNT(Sid3) = 1

union all 

-- Find PF's in CompanyMES MLab DB

select min(mProd_ProdNumber)as 'ProdNo',
    min([Timestamp])as 'TimeS',
    min(CheckType) as 'type',
    min(Mixer) as 'Mixer'

from [CompanyMES].[dbo].[mLab]  

where mProd_ProdNumber IN 
(
    -- Find failed DFs or scrap wos products
    SELECT [mProd_ProdNumber]
    from [CompanyMES].[dbo].[mLab]  
    where (CheckType = 'PF' ) 
)
-- Limit Results to instances with only 1 record
AND [Timestamp] > DATEADD( d, @daysback, getdate())
group by mProd_ProdNumber 
having COUNT(mProd_ProdNumber) < 2 
order by TimeS Desc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example data and results:

```
ProdNo   Type
=================
'1111'   'PF' 
'1111'   'PR' 
'1112'   'PR'  
'1113'   'PF' 
'1114'   'Failed'
```

ProdNo 1111 shouldn't return anything as it has 2 records as well as a PR exists.
1113 and 1114 should return results as they both have only 1 record as well as have PF and Failed Types

Comment: Do you mean actually different databases, or simply different tables (which is what you seem to have)?  And when you ask for 'limited to less than two rows', do you mean _per-table_, or _total_, or some combination?

Comment: It is actually tables from two different Databases, but that doesn't seem to giving me any trouble here. Sorry of the bad descriptions. A ProdNo can have more than 1 entry, like ProdNo 1111 has two records, one of them a PF in the Type column, the other a PR. I am trying to return results where ProdNo only has 1 record where type = PF or Failed respectivly. IF 2 records exist in either of the two tables, there shouldn't be any results returned, as well as if DR exists for the ProdNo, it shouldn't return a result as well.

Comment: Example Data [ProdNo} '1111' [Type] 'PF' : [ProdNo} '1111' [Type] 'PR' : [ProdNo} '1112' [Type] 'PR' : [ProdNo} '1113' [Type] 'PF' : [ProdNo} '1114' [Type] 'Failed' " ProdNo 1111 shouldn't return anything as it has 2 records as well as a PR exists. 1113 and 1114 should return results as they both have only 1 record as well as have PF and Failed Types.

Comment: What about for `ProdNo = 1112`?  And for the count of two records, do they have to be from _each_ table, or can it be two records in one, no records in the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are applying a filter on the Timestamp in your outer queries, but not the inner one where you are filtering the Product Numbers.  So, for 1111 and 1112, it could have a 'PF' (or 'Failed') outside of your timestamp filtered range, but only 'PR' inside of it (in one of the tables).